# Can you use v-model to add / remove elements from an array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js and trying to brake the habit of good old vanilla DOM manipulations. I decided to re-create one of those dynamic forms where **you can add a certain amount of form controls** (text inputs in this case) **based on user input**.

Imagine you have to specify the amount of children you have. For every child the first and last name text fields will be rendered.

You can change the amount of children using **input[type="number"] or manually**.

Dependencies: 
**vue@2**

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <form>
      <label for="childrenCount">Amount of children</label>

      <input
        type="number"
        id="childrenCount"
        min="0"
        v-model="amountOfChildren"
      />

    <template v-if="amountOfChildren > 0">
      <h2>Children</h2>

      <div
        v-for="(child, index) in children"
        :key="index">

        Child {{ index + 1 }}:

        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="First name"
          v-model="child.firstName"
        />

        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Last name"
          v-model="child.lastName"
        />
      </div>
    </template>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is my Vue code:

```
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data() {
      return {
        amountOfChildren: 0,

        form: {
          children: []
        }
      }
    },

    computed: {
      children() {
        this.form.children = [];

        for (let index = 0; index < this.amountOfChildren; index++)
          this.form.children.push({ firstName: '', lastName: '' });

        return this.form.children;
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

With that in place, if I increase / decrease the amount of children, I lose all the changes (because of the computed property). **Is there a way to achieve my goal using v-model only?** Without buttons and emitting events?

I tried to use watchers and custom methods but no luck...

The expected data structure:

```
form: {
  "children": [
      { "firstName": "Jinny", "lastName": "Doe" },
      { "firstName": "James": "lastName": "Doe" }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refactor `children` to be a method and use the `@input` event handler instead:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        children: []
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    children(e) {
      const {
        children
      } = this.form;
      const popOrPush = e.target.value > children.length ? 'push' : 'pop';
      const difference = Math.abs(e.target.value - children.length);

      for (let i = 0; i < difference; i++) {
        this.form.children[popOrPush]({
          firstName: '',
          lastName: ''
        });
      }
    }
  }
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form>
    <label for="childrenCount">Amount of children</label>

    <input type="number" id="childrenCount" min="0" @input="children" />

    <template v-if="form.children.length > 0">
      <h2>Children</h2>

      <div
        v-for="(child, index) in form.children"
        :key="index">

        Child {{ index + 1 }}:

        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="First name"
          v-model="child.firstName"
        />

        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Last name"
          v-model="child.lastName"
        />
      </div>
    </template>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

Apparently I'm too tired to read your question properly, i.e.

> Is there a way to achieve my goal using v-model only? Without buttons and emitting events?

But, I'll leave this here anyway in case you find it useful.

Comment: I just noticed that there is a small bug in your code. Read the OP question: "You can change the amount of children using input[type="number"] or MANUALLY."  What if you enter let's say 5? There is still only 1 pair of inputs.

Comment: Ahh good spot. You can calculate the difference, convert it to positive (`Math.abs`) and then use a loop to push/pop each child, see my edit